# Finding dynamic elements in webdriver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

I'm using java webdriver with eclipse/TestNG.

I have an Element named 'Tests 142' on web page. 142 is always changing, it's a count of records. I used partialLinkText technique but it failed as there is another element on the page whose name is 'Tests' so everytime I execute test script, the cursor clicks on second element. Please help me construct the dynamic element locator for 'Tests 142' which can solve my problem.

HTML Code:

```
html>
<head>
<body>
<div id="errorMsgContainer" class="ui-widget-header"> </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 <style>
  <div id="help" class="help">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
  <div id="mainMenu">
  <br clear="all">
  <div class="siteWrapper">
  <div id="content">
  <div id="main" class="main">
  <h2>
  <ul id="" class="tabPane" style="padding-left:5px;">
  <div class="tabPage">
  <ul id="" class="tabPaneVertical" style="padding-left:5px;">
  <li id="items_" class="">
  <li id="items_" class="">
  <li id="items_" class="active">
  <div>
  <a href="/test2/1/p/a/projects/project/tests/project_id/1">
   Tests
  <span>142</span>
  </a>
  <div class="children">
  </div>
   </li>
  <li id="items_" class="">
  <li id="items_" class="">
  <li id="items_" class="">
  <li id="items_" class="">
  <li id="items_" class="">
  <li id="items_" class="last">
  </ul>
  <div class="tabPageVertical">
  <script type="text/javascript">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Powered by 2 © 2006-2013 v1.4.9.3</div>
  </div>
  <script>
  </div>
  <div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The HTML posted here seems very malformed... there are far more `<div>` tags than there are `</div>` tags, the `<head>` tag has no matching `</head>`, and so on. Could you simplify this to the smallest page which demonstrates your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as I mentioned in a comment, the HTML is badly malformed right now, so any direct answer is liable to be incorrect after it's fixed. Instead I'll talk through what's actually happening when we're looking for an element, since I think there's some confusion there.

To clarify some terms: there is no element named "Tests 142" in the sample HTML. There is an element that *contains the text* "Tests 142", but that's something completely different. What we're really looking for is the `<a>` tag that surrounds this text (the `<span>` will be ignored when we retrieve the text), or the `<span>` tag if we're only interested in the actual number..

For example, the XPath `//li[@id='items_']/div/a` points towards an `li` with `id='items_'` that contains a `div` that contains a hyperlink, which in this case (after cleaning up the HTML a bit) is the element containing "Tests 142". This is not dependent on the actual text inside the link; if it said "Tests 804" or "jabberwocky", the XPath would still match it. If you're only interested in the number, you can look at just the `<span>` tag using the XPath `//li[@id='items_']/div/a/span`.

Heavily reduced test HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="tabPage">
    <ul id="" class="tabPaneVertical" style="padding-left:5px;">
        <li id="items_" class="active">
            <div>
                <a href="/test2/1/p/a/projects/project/tests/project_id/1">
                    Tests <span>142</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great help!!! I created driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='items_'][3]/div/a")).click(); and it worked.

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help! If you felt the answer was good enough, be sure to accept it (by clicking the empty checkmark); this shows other users that the answer helped solve your problem.